# Extracting from an array and setting it inside an Object in java

Tags: java

I am extracting an array of data and setting those data inside an Object in Java .

**I don't know, after getting the data from an array, how can I set this into an Object ??**

please have a look at the code below:

```
public class Legform implements Serializable {

    private SecurityType securityType;

    public SecurityType getSecurityType() {
        return securityType;
    }

    // As well as a setter Method also present
}
```

I am extracting this LegForm Object (the above one) here as shown from another java class :

```
Legform[] legdata = orderform.getLeg();
```

**After looping throught this data, I need to set them inside another object called Leg  (a Java class)**

```
for(int i = 0; i < legdata.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(legdata[i].getSecurityType());
    // Here do i need to set the data into  the Leg Object 
}
```

**I need to set this extracted  information to a Leg Object 
The Leg Object is shown below :**

```
public class Leg
{
  public String securityType;

}
```

could anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Leg> legs = new ArrayList<Leg>(legdata.length);
for (Legform ld: legdata){
   Leg leg = new Leg();
   leg.securityType = ld.getSecurityType();
   legs.add(leg);
}
```